# Onchange event is not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

How to copy dynamically populated form fields to divs.  I am making a checkout page and I want to copy form inputs from billing and shipping to a conformation section at the bottom.  When the billing/shipping addresses are entered it works fine, but when billing is the same as shipping is clicked the onchange event is not fired.

This is what I am using to copy the text from the form to the divs.

```
function copyData(sourceId, targetId) {
 var data = document.getElementById(sourceId).value;                                                                                                               
 document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML = data;                                                                                                                              
}
```

Comment: pls share your html code

Comment: pls read on [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the onclick event instead of the onchange event for the checkbox.  According to the Javascript references onchange fires after the focus is lost. If you click the checkbox, the focus is not lost.

Regards,
Sebastian